# ARDL OLS assumptions?

Tags: least-squares, assumptions, ardl

can someone direct me to a paper etc. that states the assumptions of ARDL that need to hold for parameters to be valid?

ARDL is an OLS based model , does that mean the regular assumptions of Gauss-Markov are also assumptions of ARDL?

Comment: I do not think it is accurate to say that the ARDL model is based on OLS, as a model is rarely based on an estimator. However, an OLS estimator for the ARDL model exists and is relevant. Now, in a sense every model *is* a set of assumptions, but your question seems to be about the assumptions needed for the OLS estimator of the model's parameters to have some desirable properties. Consider rephrasing the question accordingly.